# Google Compute Engine: Project reset?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had an instance working yesterday at 5:30pm, and today surprise: my whole project seems to be reset!

A lot of things surprise me:

- My last activity on the web page was at 4:30pm
- Even external IP address is gone. BUT you can't delete an external IP if it's still assigned to an instance. On the website, you have to manually go through deleting instance, then disk, then IP. By default, the IP is unassigned but still exist.
- My other project, on the same organisation, has not being impacted
- My project was not under pending deletion (such projects are completely invisible on the project list)
- It cannot be a different project, since the unique project id is the same as the one working yesterday.

I desperately need to access my database for an important customer.. any ideas?

BTW: no need to taunt about doing auto snap, instances and db replication: the whole project is as empty as if I clicked on "create new project"

Comment: I would contact Google Support immediately.

Comment: Yeah, trying to update my support plan. Which is a bit of an abuse... This is more like a Google problem than really a technical assistance... :(

Comment: Document everything. If this is a Google Cloud caused issue, file a report with them. Google's support is excellent based upon my past experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in cases like this is to check the Activity and Stackdriver logs to see who or what deleted resources.
If you see a user account as the actor, you should investigate who or what has access to the user (or service) account.
If you do not see any user or service accounts as the actors, it may have something to do with the billing account and you should definitely reach out to Google Support.